# Full text search index independent of the table

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

In SQLite, we can create full text search indices as new objects, like so

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE search_data USING fts4;
INSERT INTO search_data (description) select description from data;
```

In MySQL, the only way to do the same seems to be to alter the existing table like so

```
ALTER TABLE data ADD FULLTEXT(description);
```

**What I am looking for is a way to create the full text index in MySQL as a new independent object without having to duplicate the data of the tables (like I can do in SQLite).**

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you want to achieve; why is "alter table" not a solution for you?

Comment: I want to create an index that can be identified by a different name. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a name to an index, but the name is valid only within the table (e.g. you can have two indexes with the same name in if they are in different tables). Indexes don't have "global" names.

If you don't want to use `ALTER TABLE` you can use [`CREATE INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html), for example:

```
create fulltext index INDEXNAME on TABLENAME (COLUMN);
```